# WebGrid .cshtml and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, razor

I want to display all the data I have in my visitor table. After `db.visitors.Select` some code needs to be executed. I've been searching for what exact code needs to be used, but just can't solve it.

```
@{
    var db = new VLDNedcar0._1.Database.nedcarEntities();
    var data = db.visitors.Select();
    var grid = new WebGrid(data);
}
```

And in the html code, in a div stands:

```
@grid.GetHtml()
```

This is the WebGrid helper which sorts everything on its own.

Comment: `db.visitors.ToList()` This will bring full data from you table, I don`t have knowledge in webgrid

Comment: i had moved that into answer,pls mark as answer if its does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This will bring the full data from database

```
 var data = db.visitors.ToList();
```

if your `WebGrid` bind the data, in the `data` variable you have the data's of the visitors